# How to open mysql connection and close properly

Tags: python, mysql, database, database-connection, zeromq

I have a script in python running on a raspberry to save some measurements received by an arduino.

It worked fine for a while but suddenly measurements left to arrive. I thought my arduino hanged but checking logs I got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/service-storer/service-storer.py", line 7, in <module>
db="smart_reptil")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)")
```

After reading some webpages I found a stackoverflow topic with:

```
ln -s /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock /tmp/mysql.sock
service mysqld restart
```

Then, everything start working again.

My python script is something like this:

```
import zmq
import MySQLdb

###############################################################################
########################## MySQLdb configuration ##############################
###############################################################################

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host= "127.0.0.1",
                  user="root",
                  passwd="database_pass",
                  db="database_name")
############################## SUBSCRIBER #####################################

portSub = "5566"
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s"% portSub)
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE,'CC')

############################### PUBLISHER ######################################

portPub = "5556"
#contextPub = zmq.Context()
socketPub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socketPub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:%s"% portPub)

################################################################################


more = True
part = []
while True:
    if socket.recv() == "CC":
        more = True
        while more:
            part.append(socket.recv())
            more = socket.getsockopt(zmq.RCVMORE)
        #print part[0]
        if int(part[0]) == 99:
            try:
                x = conn.cursor()
                x.execute("INSERT INTO devices (state,sensor_size, relay_size) VALUES (0, %d,%d)" % (int(part[2]), int(part[4])))
                conn.commit()
                x.execute("SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID()")
                row = x.fetchone()
                x.close()
            except:
                #ser.write("error")
                print "ERROR"
                conn.rollback()
    #clean part array for next frame
    part = []
```

Am I doing something wrong with mysql? Should I change the way I open and close cursor to avoid that behaviour? is it something external to my script?

Raspberry pi (2 b+) has 25 gb free. And ram memory is also ok.

Comment: Swithing from Mysqldb to oursql would do the trick? I don't know what a context broker is...

Comment: Example of `mysqldb` with context manager [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/) (last code sample). It is characterized by the use of the keyword `with`.

Answer (score 0):

What I see here is maybe a try/except a lot more generic and generalist. You don't know the state of X when a error occur, and there is no finally to close X in all case.

This is not the (droid/correction) you're looking for, but may help here to be more precise about catching exception, and do right job in it.

Comment: I will try to improve exceptions management. Maybe adding another one in the outer while. Also I will check how to read the exception given by x when it happens.